# Find a perfect matching or proof that it's impossible

Tags: algorithm, graph, matching

I have to either give a tiling of the figure below by dominoes, or give a proof that it is impossible.
[image: mosaic]

I think to achieve this I have to find a perfect matching of the asociated graph of the figure (every space is a node of the graph and they are connected by edges in the vertical and horizontal way). So the graph is undirected and not bipartite. The number of nodes is 42, so could be possible due to there are an even number of nodes, but I think it's not possible. I thought about the definition that a graph has a perfect matching iff `|V|=2·v(G)` (where `v(G)` is the matching number of the graph).

Could you help me to find the tiling if it's exists or continue the proof that it's not possible?

Comment: This seems *extremely* like homework to me. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Hall's matching theorem, if you choose any subset from one "part" of bipartite graph and the number of vertices adjacent to vertices of this subset is smaller than the subset size, there is no perfect matching.

If we choose 11 green tiles as shown below, we get only 10 adjacent tiles for them. Which means there is no perfect matching and you cannot cover the figure by dominoes.

[image: counterexample]

Answer (score 1):

That is impossible.

Each domino tile consists of one even and one odd square.
Blue area contains equal quantity of odd and even squares.
Yellow squares are even, green are odd.
Consider set of domino tiles that have at least one square inside Blue+Yellow area.
They may also cover some squares in green area.
But in any case it is impossible to equate number of even and odd squares for this set of domino tiles.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I chose to attack this problem using proof by cases. I haven't reached the end of each case, but the work so far suggests that every possibility leads to a dead end, so I think the tiling should be impossible. Have fun filling out the rest of the proof. =)

[image]